# Facebook Dashboard Open Graph Settings

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use a common Open Graph Action: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/restaurant.visited/

But it says:

> You haven't enabled place for this action type (485624624858649) yet. Please update your Open Graph settings in the App Dashboard.

The problem is, I don't have an Open Graph settings in my App Dashboard. Non in Dashboard, non in Dashboard/Settings/Basic, non in Dashboard/Settings/Advanced.

Comment: Who says that - when and where, after you did what?

Comment: It was an error message on posting open graph story

Comment: _“The problem is, I don't have an Open Graph settings in my App Dashboard”_ - then click the Add Product button, and ... add it.

Comment: I would love to but... 
Audience Network / 
Analytics for Apps / 
Account Kit / 
Messenger / 
Webhooks / 
Messenger Expression / 
Marketing API / 
App Center / 
Web Payments .

Is all I have in 'App Product' button

Comment: Ok, then they probably removed that with the deprecation of custom Open Graph stories. It was only really needed for those anyway, because with the default actions and objects there should not be anything to configure in the first place. If publishing a story on the default actions/objects does not work as described in the documentation, then file a documentation bug and ask them to please clarify. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: done
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1237810462970306/